# gtksourceview2: implement completion provider

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs, gtksourceview

The [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtksourceview2/0.12.3.1/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-SourceView-SourceCompletionProvider.html) states about `SourceCompletionProvider`:

```
You must implement this interface to provide proposals to SourceCompletion
```

What does "implement this interface" means in the context?

Should I create new `GObject` using [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/glib/0.12.3.1/doc/html/System-Glib-GObject.html) functions? Any example?.

When I have new `GObject`, then how can I add functions (like `sourceCompletionProviderGetName`) to it?

Thanks

Comment: Note to package maintainers: You may think that your code is self-documenting. It isn't. Explain!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gtk+ is written in C, however it uses `glib` to provide an object-oriented style interface.  Much of the gtk+ API is defined using interfaces in the OO sense.  The actual gtk+ functionality is provided by "objects" (pointers to structs that follow the glib conventions) that implement those interfaces.  So "implement this interface" means exactly that - write a "class" (in C via the glib system) that implements the desired interface (which you do by setting up the proper glib hooks to handle a specific function calls).

In gtk2hs, glib interfaces are translated as type classes with the word "class" appended to the end.  `SourceCompletionProviderClass` is one of these classes, and is meant to exactly represent the glib interface.  Unfortunately, the C-side "class methods" aren't really exposed in Haskell.  The only method the type class provides is a casting operation, and that is only to work around a mismatch between the Haskell type system and OOP inheritance trees.  A glib-class-method is translated to a regular Haskell function operating on some data that can be casted to the appropriate type.  This means that there's no good way to implement a new class instance via gtk2hs.

Although in theory you might be able to shoehorn the necessary behavior in from the Haskell side by creating a new GObject, it's highly likely that not all necessary functions (you'd need some low-level glib stuff) are exposed, so you'd need to bind them yourself (I seem to recall the gtk2hs maintainers posting something like this a year or two ago, but can't find the link now).  At that point, it's probably less error-prone to implement it all in C yourself.  I have a codebase that does this for the [cellrenderer interface](https://github.com/tsurucapital/cellrenderer-cairo), which you might find useful as a model.  Most of the interesting stuff happens in the C header file.  You can still set Haskell functions to be called from the C side via a function pointer.

If you really want to try to do it entirely from Haskell, I would start by finding a fairly simple interface (like my cellrenderer function, or another `SourceCompletionProvider`) and running the header through the preprocesser to see what the glib macros translate to.  Then you can see the necessary definitions for setting up a glib object.  The most important functions are *_init, *_finalize, *_get_property, and *_set_property, although a few others are necessary also.  The `*` is a placeholder for the name of your object.  IIRC, most of the default functions are set up by the `G_DEFINE_TYPE` macro, which sets the name prefix also.

Comment: I wonder whether it can be done with `binding-gobject` ( http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-gobject )

Comment: @Yuras probably.  I think you'd need to create a new type object, register it with the glib type system, then you could create a GObject using the new type, and set the appropriate callbacks.  Then you could translate between `binding-gobject` and `gtk2hs` via the appropriate pointer casts.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally solved the issue via `bindings-gobject`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509431/convert-ptr-to-sourcecompletionprovider