# Convert Ptr () to SourceCompletionProvider

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

I've solved the [prev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454209/gtksourceview2-implement-completion-provider) question partially.

Right now I'm able to register `GObject` subtype via `bindings-gobject` (see [hpase](http://hpaste.org/74985))
I can implement `SourceCompletionProvider` using [c'g_type_add_interface_static](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bindings-gobject/0.3/doc/html/Bindings-GObject-TypeInformation.html#v:c-39-g_type_add_interface_static) function (but didn't tried yet).

The only issue is to convert `Ptr ()`, returned by `c'g_object_newv`, to `gtk2hs` data type `SourceCompletionProvider`. How can I do it? Any hints?

`SourceCompletionProvider` is defined like:

```
newtype SourceCompletionProvider = SourceCompletionProvider (ForeignPtr (SourceCompletionProvider))
```

What does this definition means? Why it is recursive? Provider is a `ForeignPtr` to provider -- looks strange for me.

Thanks.

**Solution:**

```
makeNewGObject mkGObject $ castPtr <$> c'g_object_newv myObType 0 nullPtr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer `SourceCompletionProvider` is required since this is a newtype, and the inner `SourceCompletionProvider` is just a marker to distinguish this foreign pointer from pointers to other types. If you look at the [definition of `Ptr a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Ptr.html#Ptr), it's `data Ptr a = Ptr Addr#` - `a` is a phantom type that doesn't appear on the right-hand side, so the definition is not actually recursive.

You can convert a `Ptr ()` to `ForeignPtr ()` using [`newForeignPtr_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr-Safe.html#g:2) and then cast it to `ForeignPtr SourceCompletionProvider` with [`castForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr-Safe.html#g:3).

**edit:** After looking at this a bit more, I think that to make this work you'll need to first convert your `Ptr` to `GObject` with the method outlined above and then use `unsafeCastGObject`. Not tested, though.

Comment: Hmm... I think I need to add finalizer, right? I can use `p'g_object_unref` as a finalizer, is it enough?

Comment: From what I can tell after looking at the [C interface documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-unref), you're right.